# spaCy adding pointer to another token in custom component

Tags: pointers, token, spacy

I am trying to find how token.head and token.children are implemented. I want to replicate this implementation as I add a custom component to my spaCy pipeline for SRL.

That is, each token can point to predicates for which it is an argument. Intuitively, I think that this should work kind of like token.children wherein (I think) it returns a generator of the actually dependent child token objects.

I assume that I should not simply store an attribute of that token as this does not seem very memory efficient and rather redundant. Does anyone know the correct way to implement this? Or is this handled implicitly by the spaCy Underscore.set method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Token` object is only a view -- it's sort of like holding a reference to the `Doc` object, and an index to the token. The Span object is like this too. This ensures there's a single source of truth, and only one copy of the data.

You can find the definition of the key structs in the `spacy/structs.pxd` file. This defines the attributes of the `TokenC` struct. The `Doc` object then holds an array of these, and a length. The `Token` objects are created on the fly when you index into the `Doc`. The data definition for the `Doc` object can be found in `spacy/tokens/doc.pxd`, and the implementation of the token access is in `spacy/tokens/doc.pyx`.

The way the parse tree is encoded in spaCy is a bit unsatisfying. I've made an issue about this on the tracker --- it feels like there should be a better solution.

What we do is encode the offset of the head relative to the token. So if you do `&doc.c[i] + doc.c[i].head` you'll get a pointer to the head. That part is okay. The part that's a bit weirder is that we track the left and right edges of the token's subtree, and the number of direct left and right children. To get the rightmost or leftmost child, we navigate around within this region. In practice this actually works pretty well because we're dealing with a contiguous block of memory, and loops in Cython are fast. But it still feels a bit janky.

As far as what you'll be able to do as a user...If you run your own fork of spaCy you can happily define your own data on the structs. But then you're running your own fork.

There's no way to attach "real" attributes to the `Doc` or `Token` objects, as these are defined as C-level types --- so their structure is defined statically; it's not dynamic. You could subclass the `Doc` but this is quite ugly: you need to also subclass.

This is why we have the underscore attributes, and the `doc.user_data` dictionary. It's really the only way to extend the objects. Fortunately you shouldn't really face a data redundancy problem. Nothing is stored on the `Token` objects. The definitions of your extensions are stored globally, within the `Underscore` class. Data is stored on the `Doc` object, even if it applies to a token --- again, the `Token` is a view. It can't own anything. So the `Doc` has to note that we have some value assigned to token `i`.

If you're defining a tree-navigation system, I'd recommend considering defining it as your own Cython class, so you can use structs. If you use native Python types it'll be pretty slow and pretty large. If you pack the data into numpy arrays the representation will be more compact, but writing the code will be a pretty miserable experience, and the performance is likely to be not great.

In short:

- Define your own types in Cython. Put the data into a struct owned by a cdef class, and give the class accessor methods.
- Use the underscore attributes to access the data from spaCy's Doc, Span and Token objects.
- If you come up with a compelling API for SRL and the data can be coded compactly into the `TokenC` struct, we'd consider adding it as native support.

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast an informative answer. I will definitely try to take this approach!